# Output entire JSON document with sorted content

Tags: json, sorting, jq, jmespath

Is it possible to sort a particular array of a json document and output the entire document with the sorted content otherwise untouched?

For example, if I have something like this:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "BLAHBLAHBLAH",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": [
          "arn:aws:iam::346654243625:root",
          "arn:aws:iam::984895836564:root",
          "arn:aws:iam::636877599363:root",
          "arn:aws:iam::577836285792:root",
          "arn:aws:iam::836666644595:root",
          "arn:aws:iam::652379234777:root",
          "arn:aws:iam::339659563489:root",
          "arn:aws:iam::293576423935:root",
          "arn:aws:iam::682354689262:root",
          "arn:aws:iam::349855857558:root",
          "arn:aws:iam::398259495958:root",
          "arn:aws:iam::735277384553:root"
        ]
      },
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::blah-blah-blah",
        "arn:aws:s3:::blah-blah-blah/*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I'd like to get back this:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "BLAHBLAHBLAH",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": [
          "arn:aws:iam::293576423935:root",
          "arn:aws:iam::339659563489:root",
          "arn:aws:iam::346654243625:root",
          "arn:aws:iam::349855857558:root",
          "arn:aws:iam::398259495958:root",
          "arn:aws:iam::577836285792:root",
          "arn:aws:iam::636877599363:root",
          "arn:aws:iam::652379234777:root",
          "arn:aws:iam::682354689262:root",
          "arn:aws:iam::735277384553:root",
          "arn:aws:iam::836666644595:root",
          "arn:aws:iam::984895836564:root"
        ]
      },
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::blah-blah-blah",
        "arn:aws:s3:::blah-blah-blah/*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I have seen sorting examples using `jq` and `JMESPath` but only ever seen them output the section being sorted and not the entire document with the sorted section. Looking for guidance in the matter and would be happy with any working solution.

This is what I have used to sort the array `| jq '.Statement[].Principal.AWS|sort'` which works, but I'd like to get back into the context of the entire document formatted as it was.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a good job for **jq** processor:

```
jq '.Statement[0].Principal.AWS |= sort' file
```

- `.Statement[0].Principal.AWS` - selected item
- `|=` - *update* statement/action (to update the selected item)

---

The output:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "BLAHBLAHBLAH",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": [
          "arn:aws:iam::293576423935:root",
          "arn:aws:iam::339659563489:root",
          "arn:aws:iam::346654243625:root",
          "arn:aws:iam::349855857558:root",
          "arn:aws:iam::398259495958:root",
          "arn:aws:iam::577836285792:root",
          "arn:aws:iam::636877599363:root",
          "arn:aws:iam::652379234777:root",
          "arn:aws:iam::682354689262:root",
          "arn:aws:iam::735277384553:root",
          "arn:aws:iam::836666644595:root",
          "arn:aws:iam::984895836564:root"
        ]
      },
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::blah-blah-blah",
        "arn:aws:s3:::blah-blah-blah/*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

---

To sort multiple arrays use:

```
jq '.Statement[].Principal.AWS |= sort' file
```

Comment: Fantastic! That indeed works, do you care to break it down and explain how that's actually accomplishing that?

Comment: @TryTryAgain, sure, see my explanation

Comment: Couple of comments: 1. you don't have to restrict it to the first statement, you could just leave it as `.Statement[].Principal...`, 2. the initial `.` when sorting is unnecessary, it could just be `sort`. `.Statement[].Principal.AWS |= sort`

Comment: @TryTryAgain: The key here is that since the filter being applied here is an assignment, it doesn't change the context. So rather than narrowing down to the individual `AWS` property of each statement then sorting, we're selecting the individual AWS properties and updating them by sorting.

Comment: @JeffMercado ...makes sense, I always appreciate additional explanations and love being able to cut out anything unnecessary. Confirmed and happy :) Thanks